# MIDI to camera control interface?

Tags: canon, camera-controls, olympus

I want to write software to control Olympus E-5, Canon EOS 1D Mk IV, or similar via a MIDI OSC interface. Does anyone know how to get the SDK for these cameras? Thank you.

Comment: Say, what's a MIDI OSC interface?

Comment: Errr, MIDI, as in "Music Instrument Digital Interface"?

Comment: @Pete - yeah, but what is the OSC part??

Comment: @ysap http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc

Answer (score 1):

By checking manufacturer site like http://developer.olympus.com/cameras.html :P

Answer (score 1):

The SDK for Canon DSLR cameras can be found at:

For Europe: http://www.didp.canon-europa.com/

For USA: http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage